# Escaping URI paths with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, encoding, uri

I am working on a data aggregation project in which I need to convert XML data from various data providers into a common format, which requires that all URI values in the dataset are properly escaped. Here is an example URI I receive from a data provider. It contains reserved characters ("[", "]") in its path component:

```
http://ogimages.bl.uk/images/001/001ROY000018D03U00107000[SVC1].jpg
```

This is the escaped form I need:

```
http://ogimages.bl.uk/images/001/001ROY000018D03U00107000%5BSVC1%5D.jpg
```

I planned to use XSLT with the EXSLT encode-uri function (http://www.exslt.org/str/functions/encode-uri/str.encode-uri.html) to escape URIs at conversion time. At the moment I am using it as follows:

```
xsl:value-of select="str:encode-uri(., true())"/>
```

which escapes the complete URI and results in

```
http%3A%2F%2Fogimages.bl.uk%2Fimages%2F001%2F001ROY000018D03U00107000%5BSVC1%5D.jpg
```

This is not what I need because I would like to keep URI reserved characters if they are in the right place.

If I use the encode-uri function as follows

```
xsl:value-of select="str:encode-uri(., false())"/>
```

the brackets are not escaped because the encode-uri function doesn't escape reserved characters when being called with a boolean false flag.

So I guess, what I need is to apply URI-encoding on the individual path components of a URI. Are there any existing functions for that or do I need to start URI parsing in XSL(T)?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to start URI parsing.

The reason is that your data provider mashed reserved characters that mean something special (e.g. `/` as path component separator) together with reserved characters that don't have their special meaning, and need to be escaped (e.g. `[`). How could the `encode-uri()` function know which to escape and which to leave alone?

So yes, you need to start parsing the URI. If you're confident that there are no `/` characters that need escaping, I would

- copy the initial `http(s)://` untouched
- use EXSLT's `tokenize()` to break the rest up into path components by `/`
- encode-uri() each component
- and join them back together with `/`